# Scott 965 hub Problem

Tags: shimano, hub, bearings

Good afternoon, I recently bought a Scott 965, I chose this bike for the beauty of it and the equipment it came with, I wanted to change to a bike with sealed bearings and leave the bearings Sphere and cone.

To my surprise it said it came with Shimano hubs, but it came with only hub syncros, the front hub is sealed bearings, but the rear hub is ball and cone bearings..

I have the following question, is it possible to change the shaft to bearing without having to change the hub? The problem is that I don't know the references, I only know that the hub is micro spline fh-904..
Is it possible to swap one axis for the other? And put the bearings in the same hub?

[image: This photo is the axle I wanted to put]

[image: This axle, it's the axle that the bike has, I've already disassembled it.]

Comment: Can I just ask as a slight side bar.  Why?  What are you hoping to gain?